# Issue calling an IIFE later in my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, angularjs-ng-click, iife

I'd like to call the function immediately it's defined, and then subsequently on an event (click), to pass parameters.

The snippet works up until I make the function ($scope.appFunctions.testBtn) an iife.

- Is this because the anonymous function's scope is now to the iife, and not to the variable?
- How might I resolve this?

**View Snippet**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="appFunctions.testBtn('filterStr')">testBtn</button>
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
$scope.appFunctions.testBtn = (function(filterStr){
  alert("testBtn Clicked");
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Now in your code, `$scope.appFunctions.testBtn` is a result of function execution, wich is `undefined`. And this `undefined` is passed to ng-click directive. Would not be easier to do it like this?

```
$scope.appFunctions.testBtn = function (filterStr) {/*...*/}
$scope.appFunctions.testBtn();
```

You call it immediate after you bind it, and it will work for `ng-click`.

Comment: Thanks! Immediately I wrote the question, I considered writing a subsequent "loader" iife function to call other functions that needed to be immediately executed. From your response, this would be unnecessary code. Thanks!

Comment: @imoses Check answer by Yury Tarabanko, it might satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Got it thanks! Out of curiosity, is there any "obvious" benefit using the pattern above? can give me control over timing of initial execution? (e.g, making sure dependent functions are loaded first)

Answer (score 2):

In your case the function doesn't return anything so undefined will be assigned to $scope.appFunctions.testBtn. That's why it will fail when invoked later.

I would remove the iife and just invoke the function after you declare it.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the same function from IIFE if your original function returns nothing.

```
$scope.appFunctions.testBtn = (function testBtn(filterStr){ 
    alert("testBtn Clicked"); 
    return testBtn;
})();
```